# Multiple signalR connections

Tags: reactjs, signalr

I have a react application connection to a signal hub.
In my constructor I call a function which establishes the connection, and sets received data in my components state

```
let chat = $.connection.chatHub;

//some function to map the data from the server to state

$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    chat.server.join(id);
});
```

The problem is that, when I want to send data to the server, I do it on another function in my component - however this requires me to establish another connection

```
submit(name, message) {
    let chat = $.chatHub;
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        chat.server.send(name, message);
        chat.server.join(id);
    });
}
```

The problem is that if I omit the `$.connection.start()` in my submit function, I'm not allowed to send the message to the server.
How can I limit the connections, so I only have to have a single one running?

Comment: do you use `redux`?

Comment: No, unfortunately I dont

Comment: i have a nice solution with `redux`, let me think of how to convert it for using it without it and i'll post an example

Comment: That would be awesome. Right now my application works just fine, but i'd like to just have a single connection, instead of creating a new one for every message :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can create a function that initiate the `signalR` connection and only when it's done connecting and starting your hub you can render your App.
Example `initSignalR`:

```
export function initSignalR(callback) {
    let connection = $.hubConnection('hubURL');
    let _hub = connection.createHubProxy('hubname');

    // register to functions that the server triggers
    _hub.client.someFunction = (data) => {
        //return data from server;
    }

    _hub.client.SomeOtherFunction = (data1, data2) => {
        //return other data from server;
    }

    // connect the hub and invoke the callback passing the hub object
    $.connection.hub.start(() => callback(_hub));
}
```

And in your `index.js` where you render your app you can use it like this:

```
// this will render only after the connection established
// and will pass the hub to the root component as props
// it's also possible to store the hub as global in window
initSignalR((hub) => {
    render(<App hub={hub} />,
        document.getElementById("root"));
});
```

Now you got a single `hub` instance that is connected and listens to server methods, passed down as a prop to your root component.
So you can use it there (or pass it further down to other components):

```
// pass down the hub prop to your components to invoke methods on the server
class App extends React.Component {

    submit = (data) => {
        const { hub } = this.props;
        hub.invoke("methodName", data)
            .done((result) => console.log(result));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="text" />
                <button onClick={this.submit}>Submit</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

If you were using `redux` then the part of `hub.invoke` could be handled in a middle-ware instead of inside a component.

**Note** That the above code wasn't tested, i use `redux` and got a bit of a different setup but the general idea is the same.

Comment: So the data response from the server should be accessible through result? :)

Comment: Only if your server returns data of course. Note that the signalr syntax is not the issue here, this is just the syntax i use, you can use the same syntax you posted in your question it should work the same. the point here is how to create a single instance of `hub` and pass it down as a prop to your components.

Comment: I see. I'll try it. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm still a bit unsure how to access the data returned from the server. Let's say i register to `someFunction ` in initSignalR, which is invoked when another user submits a message. Do i need to define how i want to store the returned data in the initSignalR function and how can i access the returned data in the component and store it as state?

Comment: Because i use it with `redux` this is the place where i dispatch actions that can be handled by the reducers and update the `store`. i haven't thought or tested a different approach (as `redux` really simplified things in this case) but i guess you could pass some more callbacks to `initSignalR` and then return them back to `App`, you may need to use promises for this and maybe wrap the whole thing in a `HOC` (like the `redux` `Provider` and `connect` function actually). I really recommend you think about implementing `redux` here, it can make your life easier in this case in my opinion.

Comment: That might be the best idea. In case i do - is your solution accessible somewhere for reference?

Comment: yup, there is a nice [post on medium](https://medium.com/@lucavgobbi/signalr-react-redux-5a100a226871) that helped me get started with this solution. it's not exactly how i did it but the core principle is the same